# What are the first two subviews in a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiview, xcode6

I was dynamically creating buttons in Xcode 6 using Swift. I happened to noticed that there are already 2 subviews in UIViewController.view.subviews. I know that they are UIViews, but I haven't been able to figure out what specific subclass they are or what they do. Does anyone have any insight on this and is it ok to delete them?

Comment: There's a reason Apple doesn't provide a `removeAllSubviews` method. You probably shouldn't be tampering with views that were added by the internal implementation.

Comment: can you pst code and/or screen shot of the storyboard showing the document outline?

Comment: They are UILayouGuides. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536992/what-is-uilayoutguide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try logging the class of these subviews :

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.view.subviews.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.view.subviews[i] class]);
}
```

You'll get :

```
Project[5175:589276] _UILayoutGuide
Project[5175:589276] _UILayoutGuide
```

You'll find more info on UILayoutGuides [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536992/what-is-uilayoutguide) for example.