# When is UIView.didAddSubview called?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

When is UIView.didAddSubview called ?

I have created a simple View and ViewController app.
When I run this app, didAddSubview is called twice on first time the View appears.
https://github.com/toshi0383/HelloUIView

below is the log output

```
didAddSubView
  <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7f92d3425210; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f92d3419cf0>>
didAddSubView
  <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7f92d3425c10; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f92d34244a0>>
viewDidLoad
  [<_UILayoutGuide: 0x7f92d3425210; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f92d3419cf0>>, <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7f92d3425c10; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f92d34244a0>>]
didMoveToWindow
didMoveToSuperView
layoutSubviews
  <ViewTest.View: 0x7f92d3424bc0; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7f92d3423320>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UILayoutGuide` is  a private Apple class.

`UILayoutGuide` is normally referred to `-topLayoutGuide` and `-bottonLayoutGuide`, those are not really constraints.

same questions here:
[stack overflow : what-is-uilayoutguide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536992/what-is-uilayoutguide)